# Google Kick Start 2020 Round A wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

link to the problem: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d3f56

**Problem**
There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend. What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

**Input**
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

**Output**
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

**Limits**

Time limit: 15 seconds per test set.

Memory limit: 1GB.

- 1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
- 1 ≤ B ≤ 105.
- 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, for all i.

**Test set 1**

1 ≤ N ≤ 100.

**Test set 2**

1 ≤ N ≤ 105.

**Sample Input**

```
3
4 100
20 90 40 90
4 50
30 30 10 10
3 300
999 999 999
```

**Sample Output**

```
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 0
```

In Sample Case #1, you have a budget of 100 dollars. You can buy the 1st and 3rd houses for 20 + 40 = 60 dollars. In Sample Case #2, you have a budget of 50 dollars. You can buy the 1st, 3rd and 4th houses for 30 + 10 + 10 = 50 dollars. In Sample Case #3, you have a budget of 300 dollars. You cannot buy any houses (so the answer is 0).

Here is my solution in Python 3:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n, b = map(int, input().split())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    a.sort()
    num = 0
    count = 0
    while num < b:
        num += a[count]
        count += 1
    thei = i + 1
    if num == b:
        print("Case #" + str(thei) + ": " + str(count))
    else:
        cout = count - 1
        print("Case #" + str(thei) + ": " + str(cout))
```

I can't see any mistake in it, but it keep showing me "RE" (Runtime Error)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcVXK.png)

Comment: If you're getting an error, please [edit] to include the full traceback of the error in your question, as that will show what the error is and where it's occurring

Comment: Thanks, I have already put the link of the error picture in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when all houses can be bought and you still have budget left. In that case the `while` loop will continue and `a[count]` will be an invalid access in  `a`.

Without modifying more than needed, you would add an extra condition in the `while` loop: `and count < len(a)`. You also need to change the `if` condition after the loop to `if num <= b`.

#### Another solution

The above will fix your issue. Still,  the variable names are not so clear; there is repetition of code for the output; we could do without the `num` variable if we would reduce the budget in the iterations; and why not a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
for case in range(int(input())):
    _, budget = map(int, input().split())
    prices = list(map(int, input().split()))
    prices.sort()
    for house, price in enumerate(prices):
        if budget < price:  # cannot buy this house
            break
        budget -= price
    else:  # all houses can be bought
        house = len(prices)
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(case + 1, house))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot!